# Python get hours min and days from the seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In python using my code i am getting min from the seconds . but i also want Hours after 60 min and days after 24 hours how can i make this possible can anyone have any idea.

My code is given below :

```
time = int(booking[index]['fields']['google_time'])
time_in_min = time / 60
booking[index]['fields']['google_time_in_min'] = round(time_in_min)
```

Comment: what is the value of `booking[index]['fields']['google_time']`?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
def work_out_hour_min_sec(total_seconds):
    hours = int(total_seconds / 3600)
    mins = int(total_seconds % 3600 / 60)
    seconds = total_seconds - hours * 3600 - mins * 60
    return hours, mins, seconds

print(work_out_hour_min_sec(3700))
```

Probably not the most pythonic/elegant way but just 5 mins of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy)

```
time_in_min = time / 60
time_in_hours = ''
time_in_days = ''
if time_in_min == 60:
    time_in_min = 0
    time_in_hours = 1
if time_in_hours == 24:
    time_in_hours = 0
    time_in_days = 1
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear in which format you want to get your result, but you can solve your problem easily with a recursive function. I would always save the time for this in seconds and then have it transformed.

You could add days, months, years...

```
def transform_time(sec):
    if sec < 60:
        return str(sec) + ' sec'
    if 60 < sec < 60*60:
        return str(round(sec/60)) + 'mins :' + str(transform_time(sec % 60))
    if 60*60 < sec < 24*60*60:
        return str(round(sec/60)) + 'hours :' + transform_time(sec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(transform_time(3032))
```